# Swift: Cannot convert value of type ViewController to expected argument type SKNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm implementing and extension of my viewController and implementing `SpriteKit` scene in the extension. But I'm getting an error `touchesBegan` function. This is my implementation:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

extension ViewController{

    func makeScene() -> SKScene {

        let scene = SKScene.init(size: CGSize(width:view.frame.width-50,height:view.frame.height-50))
        scene.backgroundColor = .black
        return scene
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let  touch = touches.first
        firstPoint = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    }
}
```

On this line `firstPoint = touch!.locationInNode(self)` I'm getting this error:

`Cannot convert value of type ViewController to expected argument type SKNode`

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or if there is any workaround this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: its because your `self` is an `UIViewController` and not a `SKNode` Object

Comment: @ReinierMelian how can cast the viewcontroller to sknode or how can I create the sknode reference to fix this error?

Comment: I think that maybe a work around is declaring a baseViewController with an SKNode and make your extension to this baseViewController class, because the UIViewController by default don't contains any relation to SKNodes as I know

Comment: If your view controller's view is an `SKView` then you can get the scene from the view

Comment: @dan I have SKView on my view controller `var animationView = SKView()` and add it as subview. But I haven't found a way to access animationView from my extension. Do you know how can access animationView from my extension class?

Comment: Instead of having `animationView` as a local variable, you need to make it a property of your view controller. Then your extension can say `self.animationView`

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve? I think it's some error in your logic.